# How to use two different authenticaion methods in one document for two different recipients?

Tags: docusignapi

I know that we could use Auth Code Grant, implicit grant or JWT grant. But I have the following scenario:

I have my own app. All users are usually logging in to my app, so I use JWT grant. But sometimes the contract should be assigned from a future employee, who does not have any account yet. Therefore I want to use Authenticaion Code Grant (send him a link via email and he authenticate and assign on DocuSign).
Is is possible to use two different authentication methods for two different recipients in one document/evelope?

I tested each one separelty and works. But both of them in one app?

Comment: I'm confused, are these two different recipients? or two different people that send the contract? the recipients don't have to authenticate at all. And they certainly can't use JWT. I suspect when you use JWT the recipients don't authenticate. If you are asking - Can I require a recipient to authenticate - the answer is yes, but not clear that's what you mean.

Comment: The sender is HR. I want to send the same document to two different recipients. The first one is a user, who is logged in my app and should not authenticate. The second one is not a user in my app, therefore I send him the link via email and he should authenticate on docusign. In first case I use "Json web token", in the second I want to use "Authentication Code Grant". So, I create the document for two different recipients.

Comment: I mean, I want to require the first one to authenticate, the second one is already authenticated in my app, so he should not authenticate.

Comment: Is the user going to send via the app? (embedded) or are they going to get an email and sign remotely?

Comment: The first one is embedded (via the app). The second one should get an email.

Comment: So, you want the one that is signing from your app to require to authenticate? Embedded signing gives you a secure URL that assume your app already took care of authentication. If you want them to authenticate at that point - you can do it using your app code, but the link to embedded signing cannot authenticate. You can ask them to provide an SMS code or something like that, but the authentication was already done when you made API calls.

Comment: Yes, for them the authentication is done from my app. But there is also one person, who does not have an access to my app. Therefore I send him the document link per email and he authenticate via DocuSign. Is it possible for same document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is technically possible, but I'm not certain that's the best way to go about this. If you want to generate an OAuth token for a specific user they're required to have their own DocuSign account as they need to provide documented consent for whatever scopes you're requesting.

But to answer your question, an OAuth token gives access to any account that the authenticated user has access to. Once the tokens themselves are generated there isn't any rule or blocker that would prevent you from creating a token for a secondary user and then alternating between the two, as long as the token is used to auth against an account that it has access to. It becomes a little more difficult to keep track of the multiple tokens and corresponding userId -- but you can absolutely do that.

If you want to have one of these envelopes signed by a user that doesn't have an account yet -- I would agree with Inbar that embedded signing would be the correct way to go. Embedded signers aren't required to have their own accounts -- however in order to generate a recipientViewToken you need to authenticate as the *sending* user. On the customer side what they would see is a one-time-use URL that has a default lifetime of 6 minutes. This URL is typically loaded into a browser tab or some sort of modal window which then takes them directly into the signing session.

If you don't want to use embedded signing and would rather use the email link, you can still do that. Unless you're using a CFR 21 part 11 account users can still sign documents without an account -- they'll just be prompted to sign up for one afterwards so there's somewhere to house the envelope. I think based on this it would be better to use the embedded model, but we can support you on either path.

Comment: "On the customer side what they would see is a one-time-use URL that has a default lifetime of 6 minutes", how would the customer get the one-time-use URL? E-mail? he is physically not setting beside the sending user. He is totally in another place.

Comment: Typically you would have the customer go through your integration's portal. The URl must be generated by the sending user -- once you receive said URL the typical process would be to direct them to it in a new tab / modal window.